# Implementing feedback shift registers in a FPGA

Tags: fpga, shift-register

I am not up on the latest FPGA capabilities.  What would be the lowest cost FPGA chip that can implement 1050 linear feedback shift registers of 71 bits each register?

The shift registers have to be independent and be configured for serial to parallel out. This does not mean I need an I/O for each tap, but the internal circuitry has to have the serial to parallel capability.

Comment: Do you really need 1050 independent LFSRs? Can you not exploit the FPGA's advantage of quickly reconfiguring one LFSR with whatever taps you need?

Comment: Yes they have to be independent and they must be configured for parallel loading , no way around this!

Comment: What speed do you need? If it is only slow speed you may be able to store the bits in BRAM. (Or even do it in software). Another way is to use the SRL-16 in Xilinx LUTs.

Answer (score 2):

1024 registers times 71 bits requires around 72k flip flops.  In some cases the synthesis tools will play tricks to get the size down, depending on the tap locations.  If you specify how many taps, it may be possible to get a better estimate.  On Xilinx devices, you can fit a shift register of up to 32 elements on one LUT, but you don't get any taps in there.  Best case would be 3 LUTs per shift register for 3072 total, assuming the taps are between 24 and 32 bits apart.  Xilinx Spartan 6 LX75 would work for the raw flip flop count, Spartan 6 LX9 would work for best case LUT packing.  You should probably throw together an implementation of the shift registers on a large Spartan 6 and see how much space it takes up and go from there.  For the 7-series devices, the Artix-7 XC7A15T would be large enough for best case LUT packing, or XC7A75T would be large enough for raw flip-flops.

Comment: Apparently, she also needs 71 1050-to-1 multiplexers, too.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast: That's funny!, but not true. It is for a cellular automata so yes, there is a lot going on in parallel.

Comment: Well, OK. So you don't need parallel output of each register to the external world, which I thought was what you were saying. If so, you need to edit your post to give some idea just what's going on besides the shift registers, and why you need "parallel output".

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast: OK, edited. I need to tap off each flip flop because these outputs become the "neighborhoods" for the cellular automata.

Comment: 1024*71 = 72704 outputs.  That's an order of magnitude more pins than you can get on a chip.  I presume this will be driving other logic inside the FPGA?  If so, I think you may need to look at a different approach.  I work with a Virtex-6 HXT 565 FPGA.  This has 565K LUTs, and costs about $8k bare or $15k on a board from HTG.  If you need 72704 instances, that limits you to about 7 or 8 LUTs per instance.  Not much logic there!  I think you may need to find a way to time-multiplex some of this logic, otherwise this will require a gigantic FPGA.

Comment: @alex.forencich: As I said in my edited question, I don't need all taps accessed to the outside world, only accessed inside the chip to other circuits.

Comment: I got that.  My point is that you need a REALLY big FPGA to implement not only the shift registers, but also the logic that you want them to drive.  And with 72704 outputs from the shift registers, there will not be very many logic resources left over to implement whatever other logic you need, even if you get an $8k FPGA.  You're going to need to be more specific about exactly what it is you want to build, not just the shift registers to drive it.